# Access Java applet data before it displays on browser

Tags: java, web-applications, applet

How can I access Java applet data before it displays on my browser?

Comment: "Access" it from where? Please provide (a lot) more details

Comment: Indeed. What is "applet data"? What do you mean by "access"? I guess you could build the applet tag via JavaScript. This way your JS can see/manipulate the data before the applet is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The applet usually downloads the data from the server using the HTTP protocol, so there is nothing stopping you from using the same URL outside of the applet. The only questions is: What happens with the data? The browser can only download and save it to disk. If you want to process the data, you either need Java (and the applet) or, if the data is really simple, you can do some basic processing in JavaScript.

A third option is to process the data on the server and present it as HTML on a different URL.

Comment: It doesn't have to use http (unless there is a firewall blocking the way).